# N-way DHCP redundancy with ISC dhcpd and anycast ip helpers

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, anycast

We're implementing a new IPAM solution across all our campuses and are using bind with anycast to provide 8-way resiliency for all our DNS servers.  I would like to be able to do the same with our DHCP servers and chance the IP helper addresses on our router interfaces to the single anycast address, however I can't see how to make this work with sharing the leases file, etc.  Putting the same config on each server is pretty easy however.  Is anyone else doing anything similar? I'd love to hear about your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

ISC DHCP has its own built in failover mechanisms, which includes a method of keeping the leases synced between servers - the docs aren't amazing but [this](http://www.madboa.com/geek/dhcp-failover/) is a pretty good guide.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am talking more like active/active between ~14 DHCP servers in geographically disparate locations, not active/standby between two.

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I've found for setting up DHCP with anycast is the facebook one:

https://www.isc.org/blogs/how-facebook-is-using-kea-in-the-datacenter/

https://www.usenix.org/conference/srecon15europe/program/presentation/failla

The best approch, I think, it is with KEA DHCP and leases databases locally for each site and with mysql nbd cluster to synced them: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-overview.html

Best regards, Fernando.